# Float com valor nulo Spring

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-jpa

Tenho uma aplicação com Spring Data. A Chamar o método findAll() do Spring, existem valores nulos no banco de dados. Ao fazer o set do objeto o field vem com valor nulo disparando a mensagem de erro:  Can not set float field br.com.pedidosweb.ws.model.Produto.pro_estoqmax to null value.

Teria alguma forma de tratar isso?

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que descreveu, eu tenho a impressão que você tem na sua classe um atributo do tipo `float`, ou seja, um tipo primitivo. Neste caso, você deve estar tendo uma exceção do tipo `IllegalArgumentException: Can not set float field br.com.pedidosweb.ws.model.Produto.pro_estoqmax to null value`.

Por desta exceção? Porque o `float` é um tipo primitivo e não trabalha ou aceita valor nulo. Assim, se no banco a sua coluna é nula, ele teria que receber um valor `null` o que não é possível.

Para resolver, troque seu atributo para Float ou então, defina sua coluna no banco de dados com valor default zero, assim ao invés de `null` será `0.0`.